# ¿Por qué mi objeto javascript se muestra con datos distintos?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy mostrando por consola 3 objetos que extraigo de un servicio, y me los muestra de forma extraña, antes de expandirlos me muestra los datos que debiese traer, pero una vez expando para ver el contenido me muestra contenido que no corresponde, de hecho es el contenido real del tercer objeto obtenido, luego de obtener estos objetos los paso a un arreglo, y en este se ve que todos tienen la informacion del tercer objeto.

Este es el código donde se realiza el ciclo para pasar desde el servicio hasta el arreglo.

```
console.log(this._bolsasResponse);
        for (const bolsas of this._bolsasResponse) {
          if(bolsas.status === 'EXPIRADO') {
               let _bolsa: Lista = inicializarBolsa;
               _bolsa.name = bolsas.name;
               _bolsa.status = bolsas.status;
               _bolsa.effectiveDate = this.formatearFecha(new Date(bolsas.effectiveDate));
               console.log(_bolsa);
               //_bolsa.expirationDate = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(bolsas.expirationDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
              this._bolsasActivas.push(_bolsa);
          }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: ¿Qué es `inicializarBolsa`?

Comment: es un objeto con las propiedades name, effectiveDate, expirationDate y status pero vacios.

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque la consola de depuración evalúa los objetos en el mismo momento en el que son mostrados (cuando expandes la vista del objeto al darle a la flecha). Fíjate en el icono de información con fondo azul y letra `i` en blanco y pon el cursor sobre ella. Ahí te indica esto que te digo.

Si quieres ver los datos en tiempo real, tendrás que poner un punto de parada o una instrucción `debugger`.